# Should I use a comma to separate a list of two numeric elements when one element is a range?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-usage, commas, lists

In a two-element list such as "items 1 to 6 and 11", should the two elements be separated by a comma?

I have been told that without the comma, the list can be interpreted to mean "items 1 to 6" and "items 1 to 11". However, I feel that such an interpretation is incorrect because the larger range already includes the smaller range, thus making the smaller range redundant.

The intended meaning of the list is to specify a total of 7 items: items 1 to 6 and item 11.

Comment: **items 1 to 6 and item 11** certainly leaves no ambiguity.  I'd go for this one.

Comment: Hi fev, thanks for responding. If that were an option, I'd certainly go for that. I'm more interested in whether other people consider the comma in the question necessary or unnecessary (hopefully their answer will also include their reasoning).